# Word wrap and carriage returns not working inside textarea

Tags: html

I have a Pictures section on my website and allow users to enter comments on the pictures.  Each Picture page has a form with a textarea for entering their comment.  Strangely, word-wrap doesn't work in the text area and hitting Enter results in the form being posted rather than a carriage return.  Additionally, there's no scroll bar when the text goes outside the size of the text area.  I've tried adding wrap="soft" to the text area (which shouldn't matter anyway...that's the default) but I get the same result.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post" onSubmit="javascript:urchinTracker ('/comment/5334656267047432002')">
                        <input type="hidden" name="albumid" value="5334655700200924193" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="imageid" value="5334656267047432002" />
                        <div id="labelContainer">

                            <div id="nameLabel">NAME</div>
                            <input class="inputName" type="text" name="name" />
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="inputContainer">
                            <div id="contentLabel">COMMENT</div>
                            <input class="inputContent" type="textarea" name="commentcontent" />
                            <div class="clear"></div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <input class="inputSubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" />
                    </form>
```

And here's the link: http://www.cameronhinkle.com/pictures/album/5334655700200924193/image/5334656267047432002

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong - `textarea` is an invalid value for the `type` attribute of an `<input>` element.

What you actually want is the `<textarea>` element:

```
<textarea name="commentcomment">contents</textarea>
```

Otherwise all you have is a one-line input field styled to look like a textarea.

For more: [HTML `<textarea>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp).

Comment: <TEXTAREA> FTW!

Sorry, I'm...clearly not an HTML programmer.  Or a documentation reader apparently.  Thanks for the help.